# Test if fixed set is equal without branching

Tags: c, comparison, bit-manipulation, equality, branchless

I have a set of integers `(x, y, z)` and a function that takes 3 integers `(u, v, w)`. How can I test if `(x,y,z) == (u,v,w)`? The naive way is:

```
bool match = (x == u || x == v || x == w) && (y == u || y == v || y == w) && (z == u || z == v || z == w);
```

Does anyone know of some smart bit operations/arithmetic to do the same thing?

I can assume that neither `(x, y, z)` or `(u, v, w)` contain duplicates.

Comment: (5, 42, -100) matches (42, 42, 42)? In your naive way it does!

Comment: What result do you expect from inputs `(0,1,1), (1,0,42)`? Your code appears set `match` equal to `true` in that case.

Comment: Are you able to tell us what the test should be in words? You're obviously not using (x, y, z) to be an ordered vector; are you trying to compare two three element lists to see if they have the same members?

Comment: @James McNellis: This will run in a kinda tight loop on a platform that is horrible at branching, so yes, this will most probably improve performance.

Comment: @pmg (42, 42, 42) isn't a strict set, it's a multiset. If you assume duplicates aren't allowed the original algorithm appears to work.

Comment: @Tommy: I want to test if each element in set B (u,v,w) exist in set A (x,y,z).

Comment: @Mark: ok, I can ask with the proper names rather than with a example. @user408952: do you mean strict sets or multisets? :D

Comment: @pmg both sets are strict sets, not multisets. I updated the question to emphasize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can replace the logical operations by bitwise operations to eliminate the branching:

```
bool match = (x == u | x == v | x == w)
           & (y == u | y == v | y == w)
           & (z == u | z == v | z == w);
```

However, you would have to measure the performance effect to see if this is faster or slower.

Comment: Fred's comment is worth heeding though; that's always nine conditionals whereas your original implementation may finish in as few as three, in two separate ways. If the conditionals turn into branches as per the architecture and the compiler then the naive solution may perform better.

Comment: @Tommy: Yes, that's correct. You really need to profile this to see which one is the fastest. On this specific platform branching is so horrible that I would be surprised if the the branching version is faster.

Comment: @user408952: Is this what you were looking for? To me it seems like a version of your code but by replacing boolean with binary logic loosing the short-circuit. In your version **and** in this version you still have to do the branching based on the value of *match*.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the platform can perform `a = (b==c)` without a branch. If it can't, then this version is almost certainly slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate a bunch of unequal vectors up front by converting to unsigned and comparing the sums before doing the real test.

Comment: sums can overflow (above INT_MAX or below INT_MIN) and generate UB

Comment: @pmg: integers can be converted to unsigned ;-p

Comment: Converting to unsigned works :) ... I'm not sure adding first is an improvement though

Answer (score 2):

If a and b are the same then `a^b` is zero. So `!(a^b)` is non-zero only when a and b are the same. Supposing your platform can do logical 'not' without a branch, you can therefore test whether a is a member of (u, v, w) with a single branch using:

```
if(!(a^u) | !(a^v) | !(a^w))
```

And hence whether all of (x, y, z) are members of (u, v, w) using:

```
if(
    (!(a^u) | !(a^v) | !(a^w))) &
    (!(b^u) | !(b^v) | !(b^w))) &
    (!(c^u) | !(c^v) | !(c^w))))
```

i.e. just doing a bitwise and on the various results, and again only a single branch.

If your platform needs a branch to perform `!`, e.g. if it's performed essentially as `a ? 0 : -1`, then that's ten conditionals and no better than the naive solution.

Comment: If `!(a ^ b)` doesn't branch I imagine a decent compiler would compile `a == b` to `!(a ^ b)` for efficiency. Most implementations don't branch for `==`. They have to branch on `||` and `&&` to achieve the short-circuit behavior.

Comment: You can reduce this to `match = ~(((x^u)&(x^v)&(x^w))|((x^u)&...(z^w)))`, and avoid the logical !

Comment: @AShelly is there not a risk that e.g. x and u will differ only in the seventh bit, x and v in the sixth, x and w in the fifth, and hence (x^u)&(x^v)&(x^w) will be zero even though x isn't equal to u, v or w?

Comment: @Tommy, good point - that's the danger of trying to treat bitwise operations exactly like the logical counterpart.  I retract my comment.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: that would make my answer exactly equivalent in generated code to the accepted answer by FredOverflow, which I failed to spot in advance. But interesting to note.

Comment: In theory, if branching is really expensive a compiler could optimize out the short-circuit behavior if there's no observable difference in behavior. This would be true if the right-hand side does not have side effects and does not use pointers, or only performs reads from addresses that have previously been read or written (in which case they're either valid, or the program has already invoked UB so it doesn't matter what happens next).

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no way to do this without branching.

If you are willing to inline-assembly you can do this with some `CMPXCHG` instructions.

Comment: To be more specific: the chain you will have to program is this: x->u, x->v, x->w, A, y->u, y->v, y->w, B, z->u, z->v, z->w, C. "x->u" symbolizes x is in eax and u is the first `cmpxchg` operand (or other compare-and-swap on your platform). The second operand of the cmpxchg is always 1. You can then use the points marked with ABC to insert the cmpxchg's that compare the result (was the 1 set?) and swap the instructionpointer with the target of the jump. No branching.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As pointed out in the comments, your 'naive' way matches whenever all the elements in (x,y,z) are contained in the set (u,v,w).  If you really want to test if the sets are equivalent, you probably want</strike>

```
 (x==u && ((y==v && z==w) || (y==w && z==v))) ||
 (y==u && ((z==v && x==w) || (x==w && z==v))) ||
 (z==u && ((x==v && y==w) || (y==w && x==v)));
```

You can quickly filter out many mismatches with

```
  bad = (x+y+z) - (u+v+w);
```

Some processors have a non-branching 'min' and 'max' instructions, which would allow you to do

```
  a = min(x,y)
  b = max(x,y)
  c = min(b,z)
  x = min(a,c)
  y = max(a,c)
  z = max(b,z) 
  //repeat sorting sequence for u,v,w
  match = (x==u)&(y==v)&(z==w);
```

Comment: Wikpedia: In computer science, a set is an abstract data structure that can store certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated values

Comment: Ok, with no repeats, the expanded test is unneeded, your method works.

Comment: Noted elsewhere already, but you should cast to an unsigned type (unless you're using one from the start) before summing to prevent overflow.